# ms access insert error: Data type mismatch in criteria expression

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have looked at this for hours and can't seem to figure out what is causing the datatype mismatch.  I am trying to insert from asp.net to a access database

insert statement:
(ignore the poor practice with the concat parameters)

```
 Dim BSSQL As String = "insert into bodyshop (startdate, enddate, frontbump, rearbump, touchup, other, vehicleid)" & _
        "values('" & StartDateBodyShopTXT.Text & "','" & FinishDateBodyShopTXT.Text & "','" & FrntBumpCHK.Checked & "','" & RearBumpCHK.Checked & "','" & TouchUpCHK.Checked & "','" & OtherTXT.Text & "','" & insertidvehicle.ToString() & "')"
    Dim cmdinsertintoBS As New OleDbCommand(BSSQL, conn)
    conn.Open()
    cmdinsertintoBS.ExecuteNonQuery() 'error thrown here
    conn.Close()
```

here is a snapshot of the table:

[image]

the format of the yes/no fields is "true/false"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't place single quotes around the checkbox values, e.g.

```
Dim BSSQL As String = 
    "insert into bodyshop (startdate, enddate, frontbump, rearbump, touchup, other, vehicleid)" 
     & "values ('" & StartDateBodyShopTXT.Text & "','" & FinishDateBodyShopTXT.Text & "'," & _
    FrntBumpCHK.Checked & "," & RearBumpCHK.Checked & "," & TouchUpCHK.Checked & ",'" & _
    OtherTXT.Text & "','" & insertidvehicle.ToString() & "')"
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `parameters` instead of hard-coded sql string.

```
Dim BSSQL As String = "insert into bodyshop (startdate, enddate, frontbump, rearbump, 
   touchup, other, vehicleid) values (@startdate, @enddate, @frontbump, @rearbump, 
                                      @touchup, @other, @vehicleid)"
Dim cmdinsertintoBS As New OleDbCommand(BSSQL, conn)
cmdinsertintoBS.Parameters.Add("@startdate",OleDbType.VarChar,20).Value=StartDateBodyShopTXT.Text
...
```